# Adding a new setting in Settings.setting file

Tags: c#, .net, settings

This is the code i am using to add a new setting to the settings.settings file but it is not working.

```
System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("CustomSetting");

property.DefaultValue = "Default";
property.IsReadOnly = false;
property.PropertyType = typeof(string);
property.Provider = Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];
property.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());

Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
// Load settings now.
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
// Update the user itnerface.

Properties.Settings.Default["CustomSetting"] = txt_Cipher.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
txt_Cipher.Text = string.Empty;
```

The new setting is not being added in the settings file. This is the new code i have been trying according to sumesh's reply.

```
System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("CI");
                Properties.Settings.Default["CI"] = txt_Cipher.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
                txt_Cipher.Text = string.Empty;
```

I have already created a setting in the settings.setting file as said in the Image by sumesh.

Comment: does the code throws any Exception?

Comment: No it doesnt, but I cant see any changes in the settings file

Comment: i think no CustomSetting is added , because once it is added Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property); will throws key already exist error.

Comment: are you manually adding a customSettings in Settings.settings?

Comment: I have added a setting called newsetting in the setting file. That is still there but apart from that the new setting is not added. Also I am not getting any exception.

Comment: check my answer and let me inform the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CustomSetting manually in your settings.settings file

```
System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("CustomSetting");


Properties.Settings.Default["CustomSetting"] = txt_Cipher.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
txt_Cipher.Text = string.Empty;
```

use this code to update the settings

its working fine for me and an xml file is created for this settings as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="CustomSetting" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Please add customsSettings as shown in the picture

Comment: While Adding custom settings what should be the scope?

Comment: we can set user level and application level scopes

Comment: But when I set the scope to Application level it shows error that that the setting is get only

Comment: what is your actual need?

Comment: Thank you for the reply and update. But I still am not getting the settings file updated. I added a setting in settings file and tried to update it with the code above, but not working. Should I set the properties of the settings file to anything specific?

Comment: Where you looking for the Settings file?

Comment: In A properties folder in the Application Folder.

Comment: I have added the custom setting as mentioned in the picture but not yet getting the answer, I may be doing something wrong , may be a simple thing, but i cant identify it

Comment: Its working as the change is not visible in Settings.settings file but dynamically available.

Comment: Check the modification? did u found such an xml in your system?